# Wrong caret position on iOS/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I'm building a pretty complex web app using HTML/CSS/js. It was tested and works on all major browsers, but also tested on various no-name desktop and mobile browsers. Everything just worked fine...

But when I tried it on iPhone or iPad using Safari, I noticed that when I click an input field (especially in landscape mode, but sometimes on the portrait as well), the caret goes below the input field.

I dig through Google for the whole day searching for solutions, already tried every possible workaround listed here on StackOverflow, but no success.
Starting from adding `position:fixed` to the body and `position:absolute` to the container, to the most sophisticated Javascript workarounds, but none of them worked.

I also need to mention that my input fields are NOT inside a modal window.

I have a lot of input fields, and my whole site was built around AJAX, so I need a solution that just works well on dynamically added inputs.

Because everything else failed, I need a hard workaround, like hiding the caret and re-draw it using js, disable the body scroll when the keyboard comes up, or something else. I tried some of these, but I faced another problem that I cant just show up the keyboard using `$(elem).focus().`

Please don't blame me because I haven't posted any code; I already tried everything listed on SO and Google for this problem, but still without any luck.

Here's the login page:

```css
html,body {position:fixed;width:100vw;height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;background:#98bede}
input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select,.form-ctrl > button, .login button, div[contenteditable] {display:block;width:100%;height:30px;margin:0;padding:0;background:#fff;border:none;outline:none;border-radius:3px;}
.login-box {position:fixed;left:50%;top:50%;width:75%;max-width:500px;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);}
.login {width:100%;height:130px;box-sizing:border-box;padding:10px;margin:0 auto;border-radius:3px;}
.login input[type="text"],.login input[type="password"],#eeszt-login input, .login div[contenteditable] {margin-bottom:10px;float:left;text-align:center;}
.login input[type="text"]:first-child {margin-right:10px;}
.login a {display:block;width:calc(50% - 5px);height:30px;padding:8px 0;border-radius:3px;box-sizing:border-box;float:left;color:#333;text-align:center;transition:background .5s,color .5s;cursor:pointer;}
.login a.active {color:#fff;background:#98bede;}
.login button {width:calc(50% - 5px);float:right;cursor:pointer;transition:background .5s,color .5s;}   
.login-box {position:relative;max-width:75%;left:0;margin-left:12.5%;top:0;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;transform:none;}
#forgot {font-size:12px;}
#forgot.active + button {font-size:12px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <header class="logo-center">
            <img class="logo center" src="https://dokirex.hu/css/img/ks_logo.png" />
        </header>
        <div class="login-box">
            <section class="login">
                <form id="login-form" action="/login" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <a id="forgot">Forgot password</a>
                    <button id="login" data-login="Login" data-reset="Reset">Login</button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please may you edit your question to include a [mcve] of the issue? Links rot and quickly become useless.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Added a JS Bin example.

Comment: Have you tried a browser emulator or a real device?

Comment: I tried both, and the problem is present on each...

Comment: "welcome to the real world" Morpheus